# List subcategory on taxonomy term page

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms

On WooCommerce I am using the archive-product.php template page.  I want to show a list of the sub-categorys from the displayed category.

So as the user changes category the list of subcaegories will change to match.

I can get the sub categories for a specific parent category, but I am stuck getting something like `if($cat->category_parent == $this)`

The code I am using to get subcategorys listed for parent Id=9

```
 <?php 
$args = array(
  'taxonomy'     => 'product_cat',
'orderby'      => 'name'
);
$all_categories = get_categories( $args );
foreach ($all_categories as $cat) {
if($cat->category_parent == 9) {
    $category_id = $cat->term_id;
    echo '<a href="'. get_term_link($cat->slug, 'product_cat') .'">'. $cat->name .'</a>'; 
    }      
}
?>
```

But how do I make it dynamic so each category will show its own subcategories?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of [`get_term_children()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_children) instead of `get_categories()`

You can try something like this

```
$term = get_queried_object();
$term_id = $term->term_id;
$taxonomy_name = $term->taxonomy;

$termchildren = get_term_children( $term_id, $taxonomy_name );

echo '<ul>';
foreach ( $termchildren as $child ) {
    $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomy_name );
    echo '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $term, $taxonomy_name ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: thank you @Pieter Goosen it worked like charm